# PHP Echoing JSON string into HTML Input value - Need character escape

Tags: php, json, escaping, character

Here is a simplified version of my code that I am having a problem with.

```
$variable = "{\\\"JSON" //long JSON string created in Javascript with JSON.stringify
?> <input type="text" name="somename" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>"/> <?php
```

The input box only contains {\
I need a way to escape the entire JSON string

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're outputting into an HTML context, so you need html-specific escaping:

```
<input ... value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($whatever)); ?>" />
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----
```

Comment: Thanks body I simply use this function htmlspecialchars($json_value) inside input value, save my time.

Answer (score -1):

```
$val= json_encode($val);
```

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($val); ?>" name="bye">
```